# Ça sera tendue- could you please translate it?

Tags: traduction, ancien-français

Ça sera tendue

Could you please translate above sentence?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more context? It sounds like it could be something "that's going to be close". But I'd like to see more context.

Comment: I was asking one of my french friend for hanging out during weekend.. We both are busy on Sunday and we were settling for saturday and i said am not available next weekend and she replied this msg.

Comment: Ah ok - then he meant that he has a bunch of things to do so if he can make it work, it's going to be "tight", as in, there is no more slack in the rope/his schedule.

Comment: Note that that must be written *Ça sera **tendu***. *Ça* is neutral, so requires a masculine agreement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about French Language but about English. It should be asked on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Laure OP's asking for the meaning of a french phrase, what's wrong with that ? Maybe it's asked the wrong way but it's definitely more about French than English.

Comment: @Frank   "Can you please translate" is indeed **asking for a translation** (no language specified we must presume it's into English). Supposing they were asking for the meaning the question could be closed for the reason that  they haven't look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. "[If you can't find the answer you're looking for, go ahead and ask, but do provide the context in which you found the word or expression, and tell us why you find the dictionary answer unsatisfactory"](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Laure - what do you do about questions that contain one language and ask about the other? You could say - as you do below - that this is a question about English. Then the people in the English stackexchange could say it's a question about French. How about we keep it, because "ca sera tendu" here is an idiomatic French expression that might be hard to find in regular dictionaries? Also, the person apparently got what they needed, since they marked an answer. So, this was useful to the OP.

Comment: @Laure - I just did a brief search on CNRTL, and this expression "ca sera tendu" does not seem to appear there - so even if they were asking for the meaning, we should keep it: where else would they go, if this expression does not show up in reputable dictionaries?

Comment: @Frank You do not look in the  CNRTL when you want a translation.[Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/tendu) and [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tendu) are places beginners in the language can/should use.  And there are plenty more. People who ask questions are supposed to look there first. Please read the Help Centre.

Comment: @Laure - where do you draw the boundary in due diligence? You can go a long way with just Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is probably : "It is going to be tight"
It could mean that doing something before a given deadline will be very difficult. That you might not have the time to do something.

Or that it will be a tight game : "Les Red Sox de boston vont affronter les Yankees, ça sera tendu" "Boston Red Sox will face the Yankees, it's going to be a very tight game."

It can, in the same way, express a conflict between people :
"Je vais voir ma belle-mere, ça sera tendu" "I'm going to see my mother-in-law, it's going to be tense"

In a totally litteral meaning, it just means it is going to be taut. "La corde sera tendue" "The rope will be taut"

The idea of tension, stiffness, tightness is predominant in this sentence.

Comment: It'll be tight. Spoken English.

Comment: Answers on French Language are supposed to be about **French**, not about English. There are two Stackexchange sites about English.

Comment: @Laure - see my comment above - most questions on the french stackexchange will contain some French and some other language, and navigating the nuances of all these languages can be relevant.